# Mean value theorem for sequences

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

This is a problem I am trying to solve.  Given a sequence $x_n$ defined $x_{n+1}=F(x_n)$.  Assume $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=x$ and $F'(x)=0$.  Need to show that 
$$x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}=o(x_{n+1}-x_{n}).$$
Note that $o$ is little $o$ defined as $\epsilon_n\ge0$ with  $\epsilon_n \to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$ and $|a_n|\le \epsilon_n|b_n|$.

The Hint given was to assume F is continuously differentiable and use the mean value theorem.

My attempt let $\epsilon$ be between $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$.  By MVT 
$$F'(\epsilon)=\frac{F(x_{n+1})-F(x_{n})}{x_{n+1}-x_n}.$$

Because $\epsilon$ is between $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=x$ this implies $F'(\epsilon)=0$ as $n \to \infty$.  Therefore we construct a sequence of $\epsilon_n=F'(\epsilon)$ that are dependent upon being between $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$
.  Thus $$|F(x_{n+1})-F(x_n)| \le \epsilon_n|x_{n+1}-x_n|.$$